# Doubt in proof of Convex Function Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have following proof to this theorem: ([Source](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009))

A real-valued function $f$ defined in $(a,b)$ is said to be convex if $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$ whenever $a<x<b$, $a<y<b$, $0<\lambda<1$. Prove that every convex function is continuous.

> **Proof:** Fix points $c,d$ with $a<c<d<b$, let $\eta>0$ be any fixed positive number with $\eta<\dfrac{d-c}2$ and consider any two points satisfying $c+\eta\le x<y\le d-\eta$. Then it is showed that there there exists $M$ with $|f(t)|<M$ for all $t\in [c,d]$.
>
> Now, we can write $$x=(1-\lambda)c+\lambda y,$$ where $\lambda=\dfrac{x-y}{y-c}\in(0,1)$. Accordingly we have $$f(x)-f(y)\le(1-\lambda)(f(c)-f(y))=\dfrac{y-x}{y-c}(f(c)-f(y))\le\dfrac{y-x}{\eta}|f(c)-f(y)|.$$ Thus, $$f(x)-f(y)\le\dfrac{2M}{\eta}(y-x).$$ Similarly, $$f(y)-f(x)\le\dfrac{2M}{\eta}(y-x).$$ Therefore $$|f(y)-f(x)|\le\dfrac{2M}{\eta}|y-x|$$ for all $x,y\in [c+\eta,d-\eta]$. Since $c,d$ and $\eta$ are arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

**1.** I can't follow this last line: I think that bound $M$ depends on choice of $c,d$, so how can we be sure that there exists $M_0$ such that $$|f(y)-f(x)|\le\dfrac{2M_0}{\eta}|y-x|$$ for all $x,y\in (a,b)$?

**2.** What goes wrong if domain is not open interval?

Comment: $c,d$ are fixed and $x,y$ are arbitrary inside $[c+\eta,d-\eta]$. The inequality is enough to give you continuity inside that closed interval. By changing who $c,d,\eta$ are you can cover other points of $(a,b)$ as needed.

Comment: For a closed interval the function $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ is convex on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @blueInk, oh so we have to observe that $f$ continuous in every segment, and hence continuous over whole domain,  thanks. So, $f$ may not be uniformly continuous, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** I agree with the comment above. For any $ x $ and $ y $ you want to analyze, we can always find such $c$ and $d$ and fix them and find such $M$ as shown above.

**2.** If the domain is not open, e.g. $[a,b]$, we can choose $f(a)$ arbitrarily as long as $f(a)>\lim_{x\to a^+}$, so $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: So,  $f$ may not be uniformly continuous, right?

Comment: I think I find one if we can take $b=+\infty$ , e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformally continuous in $(0,+\infty)$, as we can take $s_n=n,t_n=n+1/(2n)$, $0<t_n-s_n<1/n$, but $t_n^2-s_n^2>1$.

Comment: Taking $a=-1$, $b=1$, i.e. $(-1,1)$, the function $f(x):=\exp(-\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)})$ is convex on $(-1,1)$, but not uniformly continuous.